# AS3- For every element in the array pass a click event with different paramters

Tags: arrays, function, actionscript-3, loops, click

In action script 3 I have an array of integer objects which I pass to a TileList control as the data provider. I would like for every number clicked to call a function with unique parameters, therefore for every image in the list there are unique String parameter values to the function to be called. How can I achieve this in Action Script?

The array of objects is as follows:

```
private var nums:Array = [
    {label:"1"},
    {label:"2"},
    {label:"3"},
    {label:"5"},
    {label:"6"},
    {label:"7"}
];
```

The TileList control:

```
<mx:TileList >
    <mx:dataProvider>
        {nums}
    </mx:dataProvider>
</mx:TileList>
```

The result is this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7
```

For every number clicked I want to bind the below function with a unqiue message:

```
function alertMsg(var message:String){
    Alert.show(message);
}
```

Example of the messages passed are (clicked 1: *Hello there*  |  clicked 2: *Wilkommen*) etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new parameter to every element in the `nums` array:

```
{label: "1", data:"Hello"},
{label: "2", data:"Wilkommen"}
...
```

`TileList` class has a `selectedItem` property. The `selectedItem` is an Object. So it is easy to get the value of the `data` variable.

```
tile_list.selectedItem.data
```

Comment: Thanks to all who answered, this is a correct answer and most simple and direct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Combobox change event listener handler using 'close' tag and add the dataprovider tag laso as you did.

```
<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{nums}" close="getData(event);">         
</mx:ComboBox>
```

and Create a Arraycollection with an additional parameter

```
[Bindable]
private var nums:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
    {label:"1", data:"One"},
    {label:"2", data:"Two"},
    {label:"3", data:"Three"}   
]);
```

then implement the detData(event) function as below

```
private function getData(e:DropdownEvent):void{             
    Alert.show(e.currentTarget.selectedItem.data);
}
```